# sklearn StandardScaler doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics

I am trying to normalise my data so that it will be normally distributed needed for a later hypothesis test. The data I am trying to normalise, `points`, is as such:

```
      P100m   Plj  Psp  Phj  P400m  P110h   Ppv  Pdt  Pjt  P1500
0       938  1061  773  859    896    911   880  732  757    752
1       839   975  870  749    887    878   880  823  863    741
2       814   866  841  887    921    939   819  778  884    691
3       872   898  789  878    848    879   790  790  861    804
4       892   913  742  803    816    869  1004  789  854    699
 ...   ...  ...  ...    ...    ...   ...  ...  ...    ...
7963    755   760  604  714    812    794   482  571  539    780
7964    830   845  524  767    786    783   601  573  562    535
7965    819   804  653  840    791    699   659  461  448    632
7966    804   720  539  758    830    782   731  487  425    729
7967    687   809  692  714    565    741   804  527  738    523
```

I am using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()` and my code is as follows:

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(points)
points_norm = scaler.transform(points)
points_norm_df = pd.DataFrame(points_norm, columns = ['P100m', 'Plj', 'Psp', 'Phj', 'P400m', 
'P110h', 'Ppv', 'Pdt', 'Pjt','P1500'])
```

The strange part is that I am running an Anderson-Darling normality test from `scipy.stats.anderson` and the result is that it is very far from a normal distribution.

I am not the most proficient statistician. Am I misunderstanding what I am doing here or is it a problem with my code/data?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly it "doesn't seem to be working properly"

Comment: @sshashank124 'I am trying to normalise my data so that it will be normally distributed'

Answer (score 1):

The `StandardScaler` does not claim to make the data have a normal distribution rather than to *Standardize* so that your data will have zero mean and unit variance.

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance
>
> The standard score of a sample x is calculated as `z = (x - u) / s`
>   where `u` is the mean of the training samples or zero if
>   `with_mean=False`, and `s` is the standard deviation of the training
>   samples or one if `with_std=False`.

Comment: Ah so I have misunderstood. What does `normalize` do then?

Comment: `QuantileTransformer` with `output_distribution='normal'` if you really want that

Comment: @glemaitre this will remove values from the dataset no? I simply want to rescale it.

Comment: It will only rescale data without removing it. It will just map data to a given distribution (uniform or normal) whatever the original distribution was: https://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_map_data_to_normal.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-map-data-to-normal-py

Answer (score 0):

As gilad already pointed out the `StandardScaler` is standardizing your data.

You can find a list of methods here for preprocessing: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

Are you searching for:

> 6.3.2.1. Mapping to a Uniform distribution
>
> QuantileTransformer and quantile_transform provide a non-parametric
> transformation to map the data to a uniform distribution with values
> between 0 and 1

this would work somehow like this:

```
quantile_transformer = preprocessing.QuantileTransformer(random_state=0)
points_norm = quantile_transformer.fit_transform(points)
```

Comment: Running the normality test, the results are returning that the data is not normal after following these steps.

Comment: what is normal for you? this is a uniform distrubtion afterwards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)